# numberposts not working

Tags: posts, limit

I've got this following block of code and want to limit the number posts to 2, but it doesn't seem to work..?? I've also tried using posts_per_page, doesn't seem to work either.

Can anyone help point out where I'm going wrong?

```
<?php

$tax_country = strip_tags( get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'country') );

echo '<h1>More Properties in ';
echo $tax_country;
echo '...</h1>';

$relates = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'propertyawardwinners',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'country',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array($tax_country),
      'include_children' => false
    )
  )
));

foreach ($relates as $relate) {
      echo $relate->post_title . '<br/>';
      echo  $relate->ID . '<br/>';
      echo get_field('location_city') . '<br/><br/>';

}

?>
```

Comment: Simply replace 'numberposts' with 'posts_per_page' => 2 ... as you have it now, 'numberposts' => -1 will return ALL posts.

Comment: What does *not working* mean. *not working* has a million meanings. What is your **exact** problem

Comment: Not working means I'm changing numberposts to 2... and I still get an infinite number of posts.

Comment: The same still happens when I use the solution from @MattVanAndel also :( ..change it to 'posts_per_page' => 2 and nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `$tax_country`, more actually the value. [`get_the_term_list()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) does not return what you think

> Returns an HTML string of taxonomy terms associated with a post and given taxonomy. Terms are linked to their respective term listing pages.

Even if you strip away the tags, you will just be left with a string of term **names**. `WP_Query` (which is used in `get_posts`) do at times for some reason fails this way (returns all posts and ignores the `posts_per_page` value)  if invalid values are passed to it.

To sort your issue, make use of [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms). You can try something like the following

```
$tax_country = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'country', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
```

This will return an array of term ids, so you will need to adjust your `tax_query` to something like this

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'country',
        'terms' => $tax_country,
        'include_children' => false
    )
),
```

Comment: Awesome, worked like a charm for me :) ..Thanks very much Pieter Goosen!!

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy :-)